# Order of arithmetic expansion

Tags: bash, shell, ksh, zsh, sh

Consider the following:

```
for i in 1 2 3; do echo $(( j += 1 ))& done
```

According to (my reading of) the [sh language spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03), section 2.3 paragraph 5, the arithmetic expansion of `j += 1` should take place during token recognition, and should thus be processed before the shell ever reads the `&`.  So it seems that executing the above line should increment `j` by 3 and each invocation of echo should get a different argument. (Which is the behavior if '&' is replaced by ';').  In bash 3.2.25, `j` is not modified.  Is this a bug in bash, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: It seems reasonable to me that ';' allows the value of j to carry over between `$(( cmd ))` while '&' is running a process in the background. How should a value be "communicated" between backgrounded processes, i.e. what if your simple case `j += 1` is replaced by `j=$(processThatRunsForHours)`? I'm not sure where in the `sh lang spec` the difference between ';' and '&' is discussed. Maybe you'll get some insight there. Good luck.

Comment: In the case with j=$( long_running_process ), I would expect the shell to block until it finishes, and then spawn echo in the background.

Comment: Are you looking for concurrency/parallelism in a code base that goes back to the mid-70's? I don't think this is a bug, I think it is the logical outcome of adding features to bourne shell decendents (ksh/bash) while 'not breaking existing scripts'.

Comment: @shelter I don't quite understand what you are trying to say.  The evaluation of j + 1 is done by the shell before it invokes echo asynchronously.

Comment: What does the evidence show you?, in one case yes (';'), in the other ('&') no. Just read the posix spec and found this under Asynchronous Lists (2.9.3) : *the shell shall execute the command asynchronously in a subshell. This means that the shell shall not wait for the command to finish before executing the next command.*

Comment: @shelter.  yes, it executes the command asynchronously.  But the command is not executed until after it is parsed.  The evidence tells me that zsh 4.2.6 behaves as I expect, while bash 3.2.25 and ksh 93t+ do not.  I am questioning if the behavior that I expect is specified and bash is behaving incorrectly, or if the behavior is unspecified.

Comment: ok, good, now you have extended your tags to beyond 'sh' and hopefully others will weigh in on this. I only use ksh, bash and sh, and while I greatly admire zsh from the distance, I don't expect arithmetic assignments in a backgrounded statement to inherit (as it where) a value from a previous invocation inside a loop. Zsh was probably written late enough in the meta-shell-timeline that a decision was made "we're not going to worry about breaking existing code". Good luck!

Comment: The arithmetic assignment is not backgrounded!!  Echo is being run in the background, but the arithmetic expansion should happen in the shell itself.

Comment: @WilliamPursell You have an example of spec violation. In this case I would rather post this to bash bug tracker (and/or mailing list) then ask anything on SO, you will likely get the answer quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That entire token recognition section deals with *parsing*, not *expansion* or command evaluation of any kind. Have a look at the "introduction" for context - parsing comes before basically everything, while evaluation of the arithmetic expression is usually one of the very last evaluation steps. It isn't really relevant here.

You're probably actually wondering about whether expansions occur before the subshell forks for asynchronous lists. They don't.

```
 $ ksh93 -c 'typeset -i n; while ((++j%10)); do { n+=1; printf "$n "; } & done; while ((++j%10)); do : $((n++)) ${ printf "$n " >&2;} & done 2>&1; echo'
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $
 $ bash -c 'f() { printf "#%d %s, %s\n" "$@"; }; f 1 $BASHPID $$; f 2 $BASHPID $$ & sleep 1'      
#1 12275, 12275
#2 12276, 12275
 $
```

As for the order of expansions, arithmetic expansion is performed at the same time as parameter expansion and command substitution, from left-to-right (also as shown above in the second loop).

I think you're not the only one to misread that section, I've filed a number of bugs related to it which have turned out to be either an error on my part or due to some unfortunate interaction with non-POSIX shell extensions. IMHO that section is too terse.

If you think there's a problem with the spec language or the implementations you'll likely find better answers on one of the mailing lists. [ast-users](http://www2.research.att.com/~gsf/download/mailgroups.html), [help-bash](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/help-bash), [austin group lists](http://www.opengroup.org/austin/lists.html)